# .Net 4.5 Errors after upgrade from Vista SP2 64bit to Windows 7 RTM, SP1 won't install

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, .net-framework

I recently upgraded from Vista 64bit SP2 Professional to Windows 7 64bit Professional.  Most everything went smoothly, however after the update, any time I try to use an application that uses .Net 4 or 4.5, I get a repairing tool that runs for a while, however it doesn't seem to do anything as it comes back the next time.

Certain .Net 4 and 4.5 applications were working, however some were not.  I attempted to use the repair tool for .Net 4.5 and that failed.  I also tried to use the clean up tool and rebooted after that, however re-installed failed to complete successfully and now no .Net 4 or 4.5 based applications work.

Any ideas what could have caused my .Net runtime to get so screwed up?  Any ideas how to fix it?  Is it possibly related to 4.5.1 being installed with Vista SP2 but then not being compatible with Windows 7 without SP 1 installed?

[Here](https://cloud.ajhenderson.com/public.php?service=files&t=8d2c5ac633bebc21d5bf9b6232d94ab9) is the CBS log files requested.

Comment: are you running Win7 without Sp1? This system no loner gets updates. .net 4.5.1 requires Win7 Sp1 So install the sp1 and repair .net 4.5.2 from the controlpanel->programs

Comment: I tried that as well, but it appears that the SP1 install also fails.  I seem to have a bit of a chicken and egg problem.

Comment: upload the folder C:\Windows\logs\CBS in a zip, so that I can take a look why Sp1 fails to install.

Comment: Well that's odd, doing a quick double check, it looks like attempting to run all updates didn't actually try applying SP1...  I'll try that with the stand alone installer and see if it works.  Not sure what it was that actually failed then since it looked a lot like the SP installer.  Will post more when I have it.

Comment: yeah, WU first wants to install all WIn7RTM patches and offers the Sp1 after installing all updates. That's why I always use a Win7 DVD with Sp1 included.

Comment: Well SP1 finished trying to install and it also failed and rolled back.  I didn't have time to stay up while it was rolling back though, so I'll have to grab the log file tonight when I get home.  Anything in particular I should be looking for in it?  I am highly technical and can look for particular records if they should make it relatively clear what is happening, I'm just not familiar with what all that file logs.  It looks like it was status from all windows updates (or a good portion of them).

Comment: upload the requested folder with all files you see there.

Comment: @magicandre1981 - I have uploaded the requested files, see update to question.

Comment: th Sp1 setup fails because the ngen service mscorsvw.exe fails to satrt. Have you disabled this service? After this failure the rollback is started and the Sp1 installation is aborted.

Answer (score 1):

This issue resulted from .Net 4.5.1 already being installed on Vista SP2 to Windows 7 RTM, which is not compatible with .Net 4.5.1.  This is additionally complicated by the fact Windows 7 RTM doesn't understand what .Net 4.5.1 is and misbehaves when trying to remove it.

It also appears that the Microsoft .Net Cleanup Tool does not recognize that it should check for that scenario since it first does a check of the current OS and doesn't expect 4.5.1 to be installed.

After further review of the log files from the .Net 4 installer, I was able to get the GUID of the installation of .Net 4.5.1 and manually feed it in to MSIExec to uninstall using the /x command line parameter and the installation GUID.

After uninstalling .Net 4.5.1, the installation of .Net versions as well as SP1 proceeded fine and .Net applications resumed working properly.